# Speeding Up Internet Access through OpenVPN/Privoxy

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, privoxy

I have a server with blazing connection speed that I use as a VPN through OpenVPN. When I travel to a place with atrocious bandwidth, I often revert to using Opera Turbo and UC Browser to speed things up, but I'm not to keen on having my traffic flow through a 3rd party.

Are there any way to enable compression through OpenVPN/Privoxy to get a similar performance boost?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Answer (score 0):

You will always be limited to the bandwidth available to you from your In the general case, probably the best you can do is to send your traffic via OpenVPN - and turn on compression for that OpenVPN connection.